# new Date() is adding hours

Tags: javascript

```
new Date('2020-10-25')
Sun Oct 25 2020 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)
```

I want the hour to be `00:00:00` instead of `03:00:00`. I don't want to pass the hour in the date, `2020-10-25 0:0`.

*Since the question is closed, I can't post my answer, hence I'm writing here,*

`new Date('10/25/2020')` Using `/` instead of `-` working as expected.

Comment: The hour *is* 0. The default display just shows that datetime in your local timezone. Use `.toUTCString()` instead.

Comment: "I want the hour to be 0, but I don't want to tell the code that the hour should be 0..."

Comment: Pure date strings without a time portion passed to `Date` are treated as UTC and then adjusted based on the local timezone. If you don't want this to happen the easiest way is to pass the time part without adding a timezone at the end. Then the string would be interpreted as local time. I'm not sure why you are against this solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can set Hours to 0

```
var a = new Date();
a.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This will fail if you are in the western hemisphere. If you are in a -7 timezone, for example, `new Date("2020-06-22")` will produce `2020-06-21T17:00:00` (local). Setting the hour to zero will set it to midnight on *the previous day*.